# a "language" for describing desired layout dynamics of html page

Tags: layout, documentation

I am looking for a tool / standard / concept / convention that would improved the communications between a designer and a developer for describing UI elements and their layout.

I will try to explain by example:
consider a design that shows a 200 by 200 pixels red box with a 100 by 100 pixels green box centered within it.

This is very clear as long as nothing is dynamic,
but the moment you want to account for any dynamic change this is not enough any more.

just consider what should be happen to this design if the size of the device turns out to be 300 by 400 pixels... instead of 200 by 200.

It can be interpreted as:

- Keeping the 200 by 200 square pinned to any of the corners of the 300 by 400 area leaving unbalanced white margins.
- Keeping the 200 by 200 square centered with respect to the 300 by 400 are leaving balanced white margins.
- stretching the red area to fit the new available area but leaving the internal square the same original size.

And so on.

This is not some theoretical Q, This is a real problem with designing UIs for applications that need to support more then a single language.
the dimensions of a button can change due to text contained within it changing as a different language is used.

I am looking for a (graphic?) standard for showing anchors / margins / minimum or maximum sizes, relative positioning and so on.

Something that can easily convey a message such as:
Those two buttons should have margins of 5px on each side, and a middle area that is at least 80px or bigger if so required to accommodate their texts. both buttons should eventually have the same size (by increasing them all to the size required by the largest of them).

Comment: Interesting, although probably more fitting on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Comment: I was not aware of its existence. also I would expect the developers to care more about this then the designers. but seeing that I got no response here (yet) Is there a way for me to move the Q to graphicdesign.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

I manage developers and designers at an agency. We make sure our designers design for every possible (device) screen. If the UI is designed for a PC, the developers will have questions about how the layout changes from PC to mobile to tablet. Most designers are aware of this and design for all screens from the beginning.

For a specific answer to your hypothetical question, using percentages for dimensions would help translate a design from large to small screens and keep the design aesthetic better than using absolute pixel sizes.